# Avoid Blazor project depending on data project

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor

I'm fiddling around with a simple Todo Blazor app. The idea is that my pages will know about an interface, ITodoService, which provides basic CRUD methods. Initially Todos will be stored in a file, eventually they will be stored/retrieved somewhere remote, using REST, like this site which provides dummy data: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

I have planned the following three projects in my solution. The purpose of this exercise is to try and keep things separated and modular.

[image]

The green, orange and pale orange are my three projects. The interface my Blazor app needs is in the Blazor project. This means FileData and HttpServices must have a dependency to Blazor. I do this in the hope to make it easy to swap out TodoFileDAO with TodoHttpService, without the Blazor app needing changes.

However, everything is started from Blazor.Program.cs, as usual, so here, I would need to register my services. This requires Blazor to know about FileData, which results in an illegal circular dependency.

I don't want the interface in either FileData or HttpServices, if it can at all be avoided.

My last idea is to just create a new project, e.g. "ServiceContracts" or something, just for the ITodoService. That would fix the circular dependency. Blazor would still have to reference FileData, though.

Comment: https://github.com/hassanhabib/The-Standard

Comment: Brian is spot on in recommending Habib.  However, he [Habib] can a bit intense on this.  Here's a basic Clean Design Blazor Repo and VS Template based on the out-of-the-box templates and WeatherForecasts.  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Template.   It splits out the code into projects with enforced dependancies, and shows how to built a solution that will run in WASM and Server Modes.